# High priest’s death pardoning criminals?

Tags: history, kohen-priest, reward-punishment

A Christian was telling me that in ancient Israel there was some rule about banishment and high priests, that Jesus is the ultimate high priest, that his death released everyone from sin.

What - if anything - supports this idea of high priests pardoning criminals on death, allowing them to return after a banishment?

Comment: You've asked two completely separately questions here, so I've removed one. Feel free to ask it in a separate post.

Comment: Note that the gentile misinterpretation is completely invalid. The idol that he refers to was never a priest (even according to their mythology) and the high priest's death only applied to someone who was exiled for accidental homicide.

Comment: To close-voters: While the question is certainly Christian-based, it’s asking for clarification of a halacha that’s clearly been misinterpreted and doesn’t require any outside knowledge to answer. If someone has the time to write up the sources regarding Ir Miklat, which I assume is what leads to OP’s confusion, that should solve this nicely.

Answer (score 7):

[Numbers 35:28](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Numbers.35.28?lang=En) records the rule that someone guilty of involuntary manslaughter (who had to be exiled to a ‘city of refuge’) is allowed to return home upon the death of the High Priest.